# how can i make pandas to show the rest of my rows info?(don't want to see NaN in data frame)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, nan

I am trying to filter out the rows which only contain numbers 2 and 33 in my test.csv table.
how can I retrieve the NaN values?

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
display(df.head(15))
x = df[(df == 2) | (df == 33)]
display(x)
```

you can see the jupyter notebook PNG file here.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHgqC.png]

Comment: Please do not use outside links to show your code. Also, show us what you've tried and what problems you're facing.

Comment: as a new contributor, I can not post a picture so the StackOverflow added a link for my uploaded image.

Comment: A picture of your code is also not something that's appropriate. Cut and paste the actual text and format it as code. That's the curly brackets.

Comment: Edited the post, thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the best way to do it, but it does the job:

```
x = df[df.apply(lambda row: 2 in list(row) or 22 in list(row), axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`df[df.isin([2,33]).any(axis = 1)]`

This will show any row which has a 2 or 33 in it.